# norm of product (matrix$\times$vector)

Tags: normed-spaces

How can i prove that:

If $B=AA^T$ then $x^T Bx=\|A^T x\|^2_2$ and $x^T B^{-1}x=\|A^{-1}x\|^2_2$

were x is a vector and A is a $n\times n$ matrix?

Comment: So $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

One can write
$$x^TBx=x^T(AA^T)x=(x^TA)A^Tx=(A^Tx)^TA^Tx.$$
Same thing for the second equality.Maybe the true question is why $(A^T)^T=A$ and $(A^{-1})^T=(A^T)^{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The norm can be written as
$$ \lVert y \rVert_2^2 = y^T y. $$
Hence,
$$ \lVert A^T x \rVert_2^2 = (A^T x)^T A^T x = x^T A A^T x = x^T B x. \tag{1} $$
You also have
$$ B^{-1} = (A A^T)^{-1} = (A^T )^{-1} A^{-1} = (A^{-1})^T A^{-1}, $$
and now you can apply (1) to $x^T B^{-1} x$.